# Get Query String Parameter from Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to extract a code from a header, which is a response to an ajax query. I cannot find the response in the dom document when using debugger in my javascript no output using xhr.getAllResponseHeaders. The value does not return in the url itself, only in the Query String Parameters, so I am trying to grab it from there. Is this possible?

Here is a picture of my Google inspect (I've underlined the code I am trying to grab.)

[Google Inspect Header / Query String Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGDxH.png)

Here is my code:

```
    $(function() {
        $(".btn.getauthzcode").click(function() {
            var frapptokenid = readCookie('iPlanetDirectoryPro');
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://[myurl]:8181/openam/oauth2/authorize?realm=/&client_id=OpenIG&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://[myurl]:8181/openam&scope=uma_protection&save_consent=0&decision=Allow",
                        type: "GET",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, X-Token, x-token",
                        headers: {
                            "accept": "application/json",
                            "dataType": "jsonp",
                            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                            "iPlanetDirectoryPro": frapptokenid,

                        },
                success: function(data, status, xhr, url) {
                    debugger
                    console.log(url);
                    console.log(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
                )},
                failure: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: what's with all the `Access-Control-Allow` properties in your request? what do you think jquery does with those? (hint: it ignores them :p )

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda. That was me trying to get CORS working. Didn't help. Now I know why.

Comment: as an aside, there's no headers you need to send from *client* to "fix" CORS - CORS is about securing server side resources, only the server can allow access

Answer (score -1):

```
function wrapper(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url,
        success: function() {
            console.log(url);
        },
    }
}
```

emmm,if the library donot provide some variables,we need to create a closure,keep them in a variable

Comment: You should describe your answer and just posting code is kind of confusing at times to the poster. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) to make your answer better

Comment: @Sand just a closure, no need to explain :)

Comment: @woodenfish that was my bad. I left the closures out of my original post, which is probably where the confusion started. I have reposted the entire script. I am going to try the wrapper you suggested (thanks!)

Comment: @woodenfish. I modified my code to the following, but url is coming back 'undefiled'. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?:   $(function() {
            $(".btn.getauthzcode").click(function(url) {.....    ....success: function() {
            console.log(url);
        },

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: @Matt try like this https://gist.github.com/muzea/74bcf884d7becfc569189efbcab29b49

Comment: @woodenfish thanks for the update. I appreciate the effort. However, I am not sure how setting the const to the url value will help me retrieve the code I receive back from the request?